# What's wrong with my indentation at server?

Tags: django, python-3.x, ubuntu, indentation

Everything works on my local machine but when I uploaded my project at server I'm getting this error at second "if" statment line:

> TabError at /home/ inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

```
def scrape_weather(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        old_weather = Weather.objects.all()
        old_weather.delete()
        api_adress = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="
        api_key = "***"
        city = request.POST.get("city")

        url = api_adress + city + api_key
        if url == (api_adress + api_key):
            url = api_adress + "warsaw" + api_key
        json_data = requests.get(url).json()
        new_weather = json_data['weather'][0]['main']
        degree_kelvin = int(json_data['main']['temp'])
        degree = degree_kelvin-273
        pressure = json_data['main']['pressure']      

        new_weather = Weather()
        new_weather.degree = degree
        new_weather.pressure = pressure

        new_weather.weather = new_weather
        new_weather.save()

    return redirect('/home/')
```

Comment: did you check/compare the file on your local machine vs. the one on the server?

Comment: yes, and they are the same

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I had to edit `/etc/nanorc` file:

```
set tabsize 4
set tabstospaces
```